# Can I combine SELECT TOP() with the IN operator?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

I was wondering if there is a way for a `SELECT` query to be made on each matched value found within IN.

Consider that the table below contains 100 records for each of the values included referenced by the `IN`operator, I'd like only 50 to be returned for each match.

```
SELECT TOP (50) COLUMN 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE COLUMN IN (1,2,3)
```

Is there an efficient way I can do this?

The only way I could think of is to execute the query for each value within `IN` which would be way too slow considering the actual query retrieves many column from various tables.

Comment: You need in 50 RANDOM records for each COLUMN value? or TOP 50 while sorting by some expression? If last - what if 50th and 51th records have the same exopression value?

Comment: @Akina Sorting is required. In the context I am using this, multiple rows won't match to the same expression value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One method is with [`CROSS APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql):

```
SELECT top_50.ColumnName
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) AS id_list(ID)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP(50) t.ColumnName 
    FROM TableName AS t 
    WHERE t.ID = id_list.ID 
    ORDER BY t.ColumnName) AS top_50;
```

To avoid returning random rows with `TOP`, `ORDER BY` is needed and the ordered by columns should be unique. An index with a composite  key on `ID` and `ColumnName` will be useful in this example query for efficiency.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY match_column ORDER BY d) AS rn
    FROM t
    WHERE match_column IN (1, 2, 3)
) AS x
WHERE rn <= 50
```

Comment: I did not understand what a,b,c are doing here . I was wondering if you could explain a little bit more please . thanks in advance

Comment: @Pantea a, b, c are fictional column names that you want to see in results (and d is the fictional column used for ordering the results). It is always better to name the columns you want in the results instead of `SELECT * FROM...`